# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a promise

Tags: node.js, api, promise

I have created an API for dealing with shop items. I have created a POST function for creating a new product item. I have created a promise that works out if the request is using 'localhost' or not. See promise below:-

```
function getImagepath(host, filename) {
console.log("ENTERED INTO PROMISE - " + host + " " + filename);
return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(5000, () => {
        if(host === "localhost:3000") {
            // console.log("HELLO")
            // console.log(`${host}/public/uploads/${filename}`)
            // return resolve(`${host}/public/uploads/${filename}`);
            return resolve("TEST1");
        } else {
            return resolve("TEST2");
            // console.log(`${process.env.IMAGE_LOCATION}${filename}`)
            // return resolve(`${process.env.IMAGE_LOCATION}${filename}`)
        }
    })
});
```

}

My POST method that calls the above promise should wait until the promise returns the 'imagePath' before executing the saving of the new product object to the DB. When I try to create a new product though I get the following error:-

> (node:4296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a promise
> at Promise ()
> at getImagepath (C:\Users\onion\Documents\Programming\Apps\E-Commerce\backend\routes\products.js:304:12)
> at C:\Users\onion\Documents\Programming\Apps\E-Commerce\backend\routes\products.js:274:5
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> (node:4296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

My API NodeJS POST request code can be seen below:-

```
router.post('/', uploadOptions.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
if(!category) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Category!')

// Check if there is an image file
const file = req.file;
if(!file) return res.status(400).send('No image file in the request!') 

const fileName = req.file.filename;
console.log("HOSt area:- " + req.get('host'))
console.log("fileName:- " + fileName)

const basePath = "";

getImagepath(req.get('host'), fileName)
    .then((imagePath) => {
        let product = new Product({
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
            image: imagePath,
            brand: req.body.brand,
            price: req.body.price,
            category: req.body.category,
            countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
            rating: req.body.rating,
            numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
            isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
        })
        
        console.log("PRODUCT OBJECT SENDING TO SERVER:- " + JSON.stringify(product));
    
        try {
            // const category = await Category.findById(req.body.category);
            const newProduct = product.save();
            res.send(newProduct);  
        } catch {
            return res.status(500).send('The product can not be created');
        }
    })
```

})

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts *the function **first***, then *the timeout **second***.

Comment: Also: `return Promise` -> `return new Promise`

Comment: Hi VLAZ. Thank you for helping. Im not too sure what you mean by this "setTimeout accepts the function first, then the timeout second". Please could explain differently? Thank you!

Comment: You called it as `setTimeout(timeout, fn)`. The correct order is `setTimeout(fn, timeout)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks. I have it working now. Much appreciated VLAZ. You da man!!